# Image in ai. file changes colors to other elements

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

To put it short the situation is like this:
I have ai. file with graphic vector elements and an image in it. When I export the file to PDF everything is ok. When I delete the image from the ai. file and then export the file to PDF, the colors of the graphic elements slightly change and are different.

How is this possible and how can an image's presence in the file change the color appearance of other graphic elements that are not even related to the image in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the specific file, it would be hard to tell.

Bot some ideas come to my mind. Probably the image has a different blending mode, transparency not 100%, or a different color mode.

For example, an RGB raster image over CMYK colors could convert the resulting color to RGB.